# How can I get the total "INTERNET" usage (in MB) using Microsoft Netmonitor or any other tool

Tags: network-monitoring

I tried with Microsoft Netmonitor, but I don't know which `column` has to be added to get the `Total usage (in MB)`.

I also want to know about what filter have to be applied to get only the `INTERNET` usages.

Comment: Is your network degenerated / simple enough that you can filter that via ip address? I mean, in my network you can not - there are different locations, so "private" traffic may go on the internet via one of our VPN links. Also, why do not measure this on the core infrastructure / Router - what is the use case for trying to get that via network monitor?

Comment: I want to develop a application for a Internet cafe, which displays the each client's internet usages and to pay according to it .

Comment: Well, i would suggest fixing that on the router level. A lot easier to measure traffic by internal ip on a decent router.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that netmon is the best tool for this. `perfmon.exe` has a `NIC/bytes in` `NIC/bytes out` and `NIC/total bytes` counters. That might be a better bet if all you want to see if bandwidth consumption.